# How to override error messages in MultiUploader in GWT

Tags: gwt, upload

I'm using GWT MultiUploader to upload files to the server. Max size of the uploading files should be 10MB.

```
 @UiField(provided = true)
 MultiUploader muplDef; 

public MyClass()
        muplDef = new MultiUploader();
        muplDef.setValidExtensions("jpg");
        muplDef.setMaximumFiles(1);
        muplDef.avoidRepeatFiles(false);
        muplDef.addOnFinishUploadHandler(onFinishUploaderHandler);
        muplDef.addOnCancelUploadHandler(onCancelUploaderHander);
...
}
```

In my web.xml file I set up the max size of the uploading files.

```
<context-param>
        <!-- max size of the upload request -->
        <param-name>maxSize</param-name>
        <param-value>10485760</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

When I'm trying to upload zip file, I'm getting an error

```
Invalid file.
Only these types are allowed:
.jpg
```

When I'm trying to upload file bigger than 10MB, I'm getting an error

```
The upload was canceled because there was an error in the server.
Server error is:
The request was rejected because its size: 26 190 KB, exceeds the maximum: 10 240 KB
```

So my question is: how to override this error messages and to change text to mine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way to edit the file "gwtupload-1.0.3\gwtupload\server\UploadServlet.properties" from gwtupload-1.0.3.jar

Comment: ok, thanks, and is it possible to create my own UploadServlet.properties file in my project and then set it to MultiUploader?